# UITableView scroll indicator won't hide at top or bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a problem with UITableView. It won't hide the scroll indicator after:

1) scrolling fast

2) and then hitting the top or bottom of the table.

Here's a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of continiously showing scrollbar]

How can I make sure the scroll indicator hides correctly as expected?

Please note that bouncing is off. I also don't want to just hide the scroll indicator, I just want it to disappear as expected when scrolling stops at the top or the bottom.

EDIT: This problem seems to be caused by setting the view controller setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false`. It seems that the following 3 things need to be set to reproduce the problem:

1) the table view bounces needs to be off

2) the view controller setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` (This is to fix a different problem where the scroll indicator does not look right at all)

3) The view of the UIViewController itself should not be the table view, the table view has to be a subview.

In `viewDidLoad` that will look something like this:

```
self.view_table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.view_table.bounces = false;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

Also, the content of the table view needs to be bigger than the height of its frame.

Comment: Not an exact answer, but I think it's a long standing bug with scroll views / table views. If bouncing is turned ON the scroll indicators work properly.

Answer (score 8):

UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, so you'll need to use UIScrollView's properties:

```
Property: showsVerticalScrollIndicator
A Boolean value that controls whether the vertical scroll indicator is visible.
```

Take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

Comment: Dude, i need to show scrollbars, but they just freeze at top and bottom sometimes. I don't need to hide them forever

Comment: sorry, didn't get that point. Have a look at scrollIndicatorInsets then.

Comment: This answer misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
    if (!scrollView.bounces) {
        targetContentOffset->y = -1;//Scrollbar does not move here, because bounces is disabled, but scrollbar can hidden.
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You should explain, what to do with this code.
2) You should use `` (backticks) for inline code or four spaces for multiline code, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

Do the Follwoing steps.

1. Go to XIB
2. select the Respective table
3. Go to Properties and Disable the Horizontal and Vertical Scrollers.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer based on the answer by 范亚楠.

In the `UITableViewDelegate`:
**Objective-C**:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
    if (!scrollView.bounces) {
        if(targetContentOffset->y <= 1)
        {
            targetContentOffset->y = 0.01;
        }
        else if(targetContentOffset->y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.height)
        {
            targetContentOffset->y = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.height - 0.01;
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    guard !scrollView.bounces else {
        return
    }

    if(targetContentOffset.pointee.y <= 1)
    {
        targetContentOffset.pointee.y = 0.01;
    }
    else if(targetContentOffset.pointee.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.height)
    {
        targetContentOffset.pointee.y = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.height - 0.01;
    }
}
```

If the table view is scrolling to the top or the bottom this code makes it stop very close but not quite at the end. This allows the scroll indicator to disappear.

Comment: This code mostly works for me but I have to set the offset factor to be 1. Using 0.01 or -1 doesn't work for me. At the top 0.25 seems to work but at the bottom it has to be 0.5. I set it to 1 to be safe. This may be related to the device screen resolution or the frame size of the scrollView. I'm testing on an iPad mini 4 with iOS 11. Curiously when I pull down on the scrollView I can see it move down what looks like 1 pixel. My scrollView/CollectionView also scrolls horizontally.

Comment: Exactly. I recently had to use this code again and found exactly what you're saying. I don't know of a way around the one pixel movement.

Answer (score 0):

In viewwillLoad()
Make tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

to disable the scroll indicators in the scroll action view in the tableView